# Does gearmand with libdrizzle work while mysql-database is down for a while?

Tags: gearman, drizzle, libdrizzle

**Use-Case:**

- The gearmand is fully operational with libdrizzle as persistence-layer to a mysql-database
- The drizzle connection crashes (e.g. the gearmand-database is locked for some minutes during nightly backups, or the mysql server crashes or network-problems to the database-server).

**Question:**

Does the gearmand work without the persistence in this moment (MySQL) and catch up later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

No.

**Details**

- Debian 6
- gearmand 1.1.8 (via https://launchpad.net/gearmand)
- exactly 5000 jobs to be created via doBackground
- persist the jobs into mysql

> /usr/local/sbin/gearmand -q mysql --mysql-user user1 --mysql-password
>   pass1 --mysql-db gearmand

**Scenario #1**

Scenario:

- Enable READ lock for gearman queue table

Result:

- The script, which creates the background tasks, is on hold.
- After removing the READ lock, the script continues and creates all 5000 jobs successfully.
- Note: I just tested the lock for some seconds. The script might crash due to a timeout.

**Scenario #2**

Scenario:

- Stop the entire mysql server instance (with the gearman queue)

Result:

- Without the mysqld, the jobs cannot be created.
- 3974 jobs out of 5000 have been created.
- gearmand output:

  > mysql_stmt_prepare failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through
  >   socket X
- PHP script output:

  > PHP Warning:  GearmanClient::doBackground():
  >   gearman_client_run_tasks:QUEUE_ERROR:QUEUE_ERROR

Unfortunately, with my test scenarios, the gearmand stops work if the mysql persistence layer is unavailable.